# Why would Tensorflow not save run_metadata?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I was simply trying to generate a summary that would show the `run_metadata` as follows:

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
summary = sess.run([x, y], options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

train_writer.add_run_metadata(paths.logs, 'step%d' % step)
train_writer.add_summary(paths.logs, step)
```

I made sure the path to the logs folder exists, this is confirmed by the fact the the summary file is generated but no metadata is presetn. Now I am not sure a file is actually generated to be honest (for the metadata), but when I open tensorboard, the graph looks fine and the `session runs` dropdown menu is populated. Now when I select any of the runs it shows a progress bar "Parsing metadata.pbtxt" that stops and hangs right half way through.

This prevents me from gathering any more additional info about my graph. Am I missing something ? A similar issue happened when trying to run this tutorial locally ([MNIST summary tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py)). I feel like I am missing something simple. Does anyone have an idea about what could cause this issue ? Why would my tensorboard hang when trying to load a session run data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I made it work right after posting the question but here it goes. I noticed that this line:

`run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)`

was giving me an error so I removed the params and turned it into

`run_options = tf.RunOptions()`

without realizing that this is what caused the metadata not to be parsed. Once I researched the error message:

`Couldn't open CUDA library cupti64_90.dll`

I looked into this [Github Thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6235) and moved the file into the `bin` folder. After that I ran again my code with the `trace_level` param, had no errors and the metadata was successfully parsed.